# When do you use "is accusing of" ? Is this correct?

Tags: word-usage, usage

I thought "accuse" is used as below

1) A accuse B of something

2) B is accused of something

then I read a newspaper saying "Condo owner is accusing of splitting~"
I googled if this is a correct usage and found other sentences of using "B is accusing of something"

[image: from google]

there are many other sentences using "B is accusing of something" but the dictionary doesn't say anything about this usage,
so I am wondering if this usage is just an expression in newspaper, or special usage or something

Comment: It's just incorrect, even in newspaper-title speak. It should be *accused* in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial thoughts are correct. Those titles are incorrectly worded

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the screen capture that the correct caption is "accused of".

[image]